# Optional arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

The last line of code below gives me this error :

```
**Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[AnyObject]' and '[(AnyObject)]'**


var newsArray: [AnyObject]?

if let _newsArray = newsArray {
    var mutableNewsArray = [AnyObject]()
    _newsArray += mutableNewsArray
}
```

I don't understand why this happens. **newsArray** and **mutableNewsArray** are of the same type and **newsArray** seems to be correctly unwrapped.

Comment: No, they don't have the same type: newsArray is an ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional and mutableNewArray is a [AnyObject], in order to add elements to newsArray, you have to unwrap it.

Comment: Sorry i didn't put the _ before newsArray but yes, newsArray is correctly unwrapped (_newsArray += mutableNewsArray)

Comment: _newsArray is unwrapped. That is the point of using the let expression in the if condition so you wouldn't have to unwrap it every time you access it in the if block

Comment: Yes, you unwraped it, but created a constant, and therefore you cannot append to it.

Comment: It would be easier to use this: newsArray?.append(mutableNewsArray) instead of an if let expression.

Comment: @DánielNagy correctly spotted. Looks like a valid answer (the let is causing this error)

Comment: Indeed, thanks @DánielNagy. I'm now using var tmpNewsArray = _filteredNewsArray and doing my operations on tmpNewsArray.

Comment: Important to note that this will make a _copy_ of whatever's inside the optional, and you changes will be discarded outside the `if`.  Unlike `newsArray?.extend(otherArray)` which will change it in-place.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I stated wrong in my first comment: newsArray is an Optional<[AnyObject]>, not an ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<[AnyObject]>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you unwrap _newsArray with "let", it is immutable. You can't append to it.

EDIT : Didn't see Dániel Nagy's answer, which was spot on